# how to force LinearLayout to fill the scrollView?

Tags: android

I created two level of layout (because some devices have small screen ) -

ScrollView that hold LinearLayout

For some reason i can't make the LinearLayout  to fill all the ScrollView  and when i work with big screen i see some gap below the LinearLayout

Please ... any help :)

Thanks

```
 <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/topLinearLayout"/>
```

Comment: Add `android:fillViewport="true"` to the opening `<ScrollView>` tag.

Comment: ok ... but the LinearLayout is not fill all the scrollView :(

Comment: With that attribute set, the `LinearLayout` will fill the `ScrollView`. Are you sure it's not just the `LinearLayout`'s child `View`s that are leaving the perceived gap? Btw, the `LinearLayout`'s `layout_height` should be `wrap_content`.

Comment: Remove the margin?

Comment: no .. i don't want the  perceived gap

Comment: yes .. remove the margin .. does not help

Comment: No, I'm saying, how do you know it's the `LinearLayout` not filling the `ScrollView`? Are you sure it's not the other `View`s that aren't reaching the bottom?

Comment: ok .. so how to force the other view to reach the bottom ?

Answer (score 2):

Add `android:fill_viewport="true"` to your `ScrollView`

Answer (score 0):

Change the layout_width and layout_height on both scrollView and LinearLayout to wrap_content